# Getting errors from deleted class

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I deleted a class from my Netbeans Spring application, which holds a method to throw an exception. I also removed all jars attached to this class. When I run my application, TomCat log still shows errors from deleted class, timestamped currently. Shall I call the ghostbusters?

Comment: May help to look into the webapps directory of tomcat. In paranoia mode remove webapps, temp, conf/Catalina and work directories and restart and redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

Logically if any of the class is referring to the deleted class then it should throw a classnotfound exception, but if you are getting error in the deleted class means, the war which you have built is not updated.

Try to clean and rebuild the war.

stop tomcat.

delete the temp directories created by tomcat for previous runs.

start the tomcat.

and before deploying the war check in the war for the deleted class which should not be there.

Comment: I have cleaned, build and restarted tomcat, no use

Comment: did you check in the war?? are you still seeing that class?